# Exclude specific result from INDEX from within the range

Tags: google-sheets

I'm trying to exclude a single result from INDEX listing. For example let's say that INDEX gives me 10 columns ( B1:10 ) with the numbers 0-9, I have a function in A1 that gives out number between 0 and 9 ( depending on changes up the chain ) and I want to exclude that specific number from showing up in the INDEX list.

I don't know if it makes any difference, but in my real case I'm dealing with plain text rather than numbers.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done with `query` as follows:

```
 =query({index(B1:Z10, 2, 3)}, "select * where Col1 <> '"&A1&"'", 0)
```

The query string means "select all where column 1 of the queried array is not equal to the content of cell A1". The curly braces around `index` are there to make it possible to refer to the column as "Col1", without knowing whether it's B,C,D, or something else depending on column offset. The last parameter 0 says there is no header row in the queried data.